System.InvalidCastException: 'Unable to cast object of type 'fast_food.Modele.usprouduct' to type 'System.IConvertible'.'
I made a user control to display the products, everything works fine except for one part
I have another form in which the assignments are listed along with the price to print the invoice. When I add a product once, there is no problem, but when I want to select the same product again, I get this error.

System.InvalidCastException:Unable to cast object of type fast_food.Modele.usproduct to type
System.IConvertible

I checked all the code of the user control and the conversion method, but I could not understand where the problem is
This conversion method code:
private void AddItems(string id,string proID ,string name, string cat, string price, Image pimage)
 {
     var w = new usprouduct()
     {
         pName = name,
         pPrice = price,
         pCategory = cat,
         pImage = pimage,
         id = Convert.ToInt32(proID)
     };
     prouductpanel.Controls.Add(w);

     w.oneSelect += (ss, ee) =>
     {
         var wdg = (usprouduct)ss;

         foreach (DataGridViewRow item in guna2DataGridView1.Rows)
         {
             if (Convert.ToInt32(item.Cells["dgvproid"].Value) == wdg.id)
             {
                 item.Cells["dgvQty"].Value = int.Parse(item.Cells["dgvQty"].Value.ToString()) + 1;
                 item.Cells["dgvAmount"].Value = int.Parse(item.Cells["dgvQty"].Value.ToString()) *
                  double.Parse(item.Cells["dgvprice"].Value.ToString());
                 return;
             }
             
         }
         // افزودن یک محصول
         guna2DataGridView1.Rows.Add(new object[] {0, 0, wdg, id, wdg.pName, 1, wdg.pPrice, wdg.pPrice });
         GetTotal();
     };
 }

And this is the user control code:
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace fast_food.Modele
{
    
    public partial class usprouduct : UserControl
    {
        public usprouduct()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        public event EventHandler oneSelect = null;
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string pPrice { get; set; }
        public string pCategory { get; set; }

        public string pName
        {
            get { return labelName.Text; }
            set { labelName.Text = value; }

        }

        public Image pImage
        {
            get { return image1.Image; }
            set { image1.Image = value; }

        }

        private void image1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           oneSelect?.Invoke(this,e);
        }
    }
}

And this is the GetTotal code:
 private void GetTotal()
 {
     double total = 0;
     labeltotal.Text = "";

     foreach(DataGridViewRow item in guna2DataGridView1.Rows)
     {
         total += double.Parse(item.Cells["dgvAmount"].Value.ToString());

     }
     labeltotal.Text = total.ToString("N2");
 }


What debugging have you done so far? Can you at least point us to the line of code where the error occurred? Posting the complete error including the traceback would be even better.

This isn't a sql server issue, this is a code issue.

error point this line:if (Convert.ToInt32(item.Cells["dgvproid"].Value) == wdg.id)

You're trying to add to the DataTable your usprouduct object in method AddItems before calling GetTotal method.
The DataTable expect an object of System.IConvertible like int, bool, string.
Maybe by mistake you are adding this item to the DataTable.
